# Multiple Spring Data CrudRepository in single interface

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Instead of creating one specialization of a CrudRepository, can multiple Spring Data JPA `CrudRepository` in single interface

**AND**

Still have `@NamedQueries`be referenced from the interface?

At the moment, I am creating a separate facade class that would collect all the repositories and expose a more unified API, but it's mostly forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how Spring Data JPA repository works:

> 4.3. Defining Repository Interfaces
>
> First, define a domain class-specific repository interface.
>
> The interface must extend Repository and be typed to the domain class
>   and an ID type. If you want to expose CRUD methods for that domain
>   type, extend CrudRepository instead of Repository

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition

If you don't like this approach you can go ahead and implement your own generic Repository.

How this can be done you can see in the default implementation SimpleJpaRepository:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java